# Ajax Validation intrupt the form submit on form submit event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, forms

Hi i have problem with form redirection to its action target, validation ajax interrupt the form redirection here is my code , all i just submit the post to form action location also redirect on that location.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  jQuery.ajax({
     type : "post",
     url : "validate.php",
     dataType : "json",
     data : {email : 'example@domain.com'},
     success: function(response) { 
        if(response.status == '1'){
          //Email is valid want to continue form submit and redirect , but it is not 
        }else{
           e.preventDefault();
           //return false
        }
     }
  });
})
```

Comment: what is the error you got?

Comment: What is you are getting in `response.status` ??

Comment: Hi ,response status is '1' , the problem is on submit event , is it possible do the validation first , then submit the event , if validation failed then stop submission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to create a separated *function* to `submit` your *form* as a *callback* of the validation ajax process and pass the serialized *data* to it, something like :

```
function submitForm(serializedData) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        ur: "{your form action processing file}",
        type: "POST",
        data: serializedData,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log("form submitted "+xhr.status) // 201 if everything OK
            // optionally reload the page
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // validate form
    $("#myForm").on("submit", function (event) {
        // prevent form from being submitted
        event.preventDefault();
        // collect your form data to be submitted  :
        var serializedData = $("#myForm").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url : "validate.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            dataType : "json",
            data : {email : 'example@domain.com'},
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.status == '1'){
                    // email is valid so submit the form
                    submitForm(serializedData);
                } // you don't need an else statement since we already used event.preventDefault() before the ajax call
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("ajax validation error");
            }
        })
    }); // on submit    

}); // ready
```

**Notice** we assigned a selector (`#myForm`) to the *form* we are processing.